# Plot using Japanese strings on X-axis using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot something like:

```
扱      1446.405        1546.251        1295.103
異      1249.171        1507.368        1281.740
江      1249.180        1583.025        887.781
履      1340.731        1407.289        1063.232
明日    1340.662        1558.008        960.340
```

with each string in the first column on X-axis. I tried to use kana14 font with:

```
set term png font 'mbfont:kana14;k14'
```

But it gives:

```
Could not find/open font when opening font mbfont:kana14;k14, trying default
```

How do I install the font in a way that is usable in above situation

Comment: Did you try giving the absolute path to the font?

Comment: where can find on a Redhat system?

Comment: I don't know, sometimes you can find it here: /usr/share/fonts

Comment: I installed Japanese fonts using yum install fonts-japanese and later gave an absolute path. It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font is not found, therefore gnuplot does use the default font.

You can give gnuplot the absolute path to font to make sure that it is found.

```
set term png font '/usr/share/fonts/path/to/font'
```